# Convert vimeo link to embedded video on keyup

Tags: jquery

i found some scripts on this site and put it together, the results is this http://jsfiddle.net/mortenhauberg/XyCec/

It converts Youtube links to video. How do i do the same with Vimeo links?

The code is probably very messy and ugly, but im new to this jquery-thing and just wants to learn :)

Comment: Why don't you use kind of the same thing but then adapt your source for the vimeo? Add a var **vimeo** that contains the vimeo iframe code and check if your content contains vimeo.

Comment: I can't get it to work. As i said I'm new :)
Could you help me?

Comment: Give us your try at the vimeo code instead, not the working one with youtube. Then we can help you with what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I have tried something new. Hope you guys can help me.

http://jsfiddle.net/mortenhauberg/SwH7D/

This script can append the youtube video, but not the vimeo. I found the script at http://labs.steveottenad.com/jquery-to-parse-youtube-vimeo-urls/ and thought that it look cleaner. It just can't get it to work with vimeo!

And how can i delete the address after i append the video? Otherwise it will append a new video every time a key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I put notes on everything so between that and the demo, everything should be pretty clear.

[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/UMiTEpe/1/edit)

```
<!-- this is where you can put the url that will be loaded into the iframe -->
<input id="vimeoInput" type="text" placeholder="Vimeo video url">
<!-- make a video from a url by adding the "src" to this iframe -->
<iframe id="vimeoFrame" src=""></iframe>
```

javascript:

```
/* get element references */
var vimeoFrame = document.getElementById('vimeoFrame');
var vimeoInput = document.getElementById('vimeoInput');
var vimeoUrlList = document.getElementById('vimeoUrlList');

function updateIframe() {
  if (this.value) { //if the input isn't empty
    vimeoFrame.src = this.value; //add the value as the iframe source
    vimeoFrame.style.display = 'block'; //show iframe
  }
  else { //no input value
    vimeoFrame.style.display = 'none'; //hide iframe
  }
}

vimeoInput.addEventListener('keyup', updateIframe); //when typing in the input, run updateIframe function
```